# Issues in Implementing a Drop Down with Knockout

Tags: javascript, jquery, knockout.js

I am trying to replace a text box in the existing website with a dropdown menu with few options in it. Everything is working fine expect the value is not being stored/registered when the person hits register. But with the text box it works fine. Please see the code below that i have made for the drop down:

```
</label>
<label class="label-4 lcol1" for="d_name-suffix"><small>(optional)</small>
<select id="d_name-suffix" style="width:auto; height:auto" data-bind="options: $root.nameSuffix, value: nameSuffix, optionsText: 'options1'" />
</label>
```

JS:

```
self.nameSuffix = ko.observable([
{ options1: "Mr" },
{ options1: "Mrs" },
{ options1: "Miss" }
]).extend({ pattern: NineElevenRegistries.inputValidation.name });
```

And here is the code that was implemented for the textbox:

```
self.nameSuffix = ko.observable().extend({
maxLength: NineElevenRegistries.inputValidation.nameSuffixMaxLength,
pattern: NineElevenRegistries.inputValidation.name
});
```

Answer (score 1):

You need to use an array for the values and store the value in an observable.

```
self.nameSuffixes = ko.observableArray([
{ options1: "Mr" },
{ options1: "Mrs" },
{ options1: "Miss" }
]);

self.nameSuffix = ko.observable();
```

And in your view -

```
<select id="d_name-suffix" style="width:auto; height:auto" data-bind="options: $root.nameSuffixes, value: nameSuffix, optionsText: 'options1'" />
```

Answer (score 0):

So actually i figured out the solution to this problem. Instead of making Mr, Mrs etc as objects, i created string using the following array:

```
self.nameSuffixes = ko.observableArray([ "","Mr.","Mrs","Miss"]);
self.nameSuffix = ko.observable();
```